# Automatically close a program if another program starts

Tags: windows, automation, windows-10, task, windows-task-scheduler

I am using "**Program_A**". Now, if I want to use "**Program_B**", I have to close "**Program_A**". Is there any way to close "**Program_A**" automatically on windows if I open "**Program_B**"?

I am using windows 10.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: scan processes and kill them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're trying to do is easy, but there's a workaround: you can create a batchfile, which closes `Program_A` (using `taskkill`) and then starts `Program_B`, and instead of starting up `Program_B` as you usually do, use the batchfile.